# how to merge go templates without render

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

for example, I want to merge two template below,

```
# v1
instance_db_address: {{ .MYSQL_ADDRESS }}
instance_db_port: {{ .MYSQL_PORT }}
imagePullSecrets: {{ .IMAGE_PULL_SECRET }}
resources:
  requests:
    memory: "1Gi"
    cpu: "512m"
  limits:
    memory: "1Gi"
    cpu: "1000m"
```

```
# v2
instance_db_address: {{ .MYSQL_ADDRESS2 }}
instance_db_port: {{ .MYSQL_PORT2 }}
```

the answer should be

```
instance_db_address: {{ .MYSQL_ADDRESS2 }}
instance_db_port: {{ .MYSQL_PORT2 }}
imagePullSecrets: {{ .IMAGE_PULL_SECRET }}
resources:
  requests:
    memory: "1Gi"
    cpu: "512m"
  limits:
    memory: "1Gi"
    cpu: "1000m"
```

I found it's difficult to merge because these are not yamls, could someone can help me ?

I have tried to add some quotation marks to the braces each line, but I want to keep the braces without quotation marks. So it didn't work well.

Comment: Can you not render them individually first, then merge them?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include the code you've already written?  In Helm, there are two layers.  It'd be unusual to see this sort of template expression in values (configuration) files; inside the actual template code, Helm provides a [`merge`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#merge-mustmerge) function that does what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you're using `text/template` to process these templates, you can (and should) merge the so-called "parse trees"–which are what templates are parsed into (and what is actually `Execute`d),–not the source text of the templates.

One approach to do this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "text/template"
    "text/template/parse"
)

const t1Text = `instance_db_address: {{ .MYSQL_ADDRESS }}
instance_db_port: {{ .MYSQL_PORT }}
imagePullSecrets: {{ .IMAGE_PULL_SECRET }}
resources:
  requests:
    memory: "1Gi"
    cpu: "512m"
  limits:
    memory: "1Gi"
    cpu: "1000m"
`

const t2Text = `instance_db_address: {{ .MYSQL_ADDRESS2 }}
instance_db_port: {{ .MYSQL_PORT2 }}
`

func merge(dst, src *template.Template) error {
    dstNodes := dst.Tree.Root.Nodes
    a1, p1, err := findAddrAndPortNodes(dstNodes)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    srcNodes := src.Tree.Root.Nodes
    a2, p2, err := findAddrAndPortNodes(srcNodes)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    dstNodes[a1] = srcNodes[a2]
    dstNodes[p1] = srcNodes[p2]

    return nil
}

func findAddrAndPortNodes(nodes []parse.Node) (
    addrIndex int, portIndex int, err error) {

    type curNode struct {
        text         string
        nodeIndexPtr *int
    }

    const (
        modeText = iota
        modeAction
    )

    toLocate := map[string]*int{
        "instance_db_address:": &addrIndex,
        "instance_db_port:":    &portIndex,
    }

    var cur curNode

    mode := modeText
NODE_LOOP:
    for ix, n := range nodes {
        switch mode {
        case modeText:
            tn, ok := n.(*parse.TextNode)
            if !ok {
                continue
            }

            nodeText := strings.TrimSpace(string(tn.Text))
            for text, dst := range toLocate {
                if nodeText != text {
                    continue
                }

                cur.text = text
                cur.nodeIndexPtr = dst
                mode = modeAction

                continue NODE_LOOP
            }
        case modeAction:
            _, ok := n.(*parse.ActionNode)
            if !ok {
                return 0, 0, fmt.Errorf(
                    "unexpected node type: %T for %q", n, cur.text)
            }

            *cur.nodeIndexPtr = ix

            delete(toLocate, cur.text)
            if len(toLocate) == 0 {
                break NODE_LOOP
            }

            mode = modeText
            continue
        }
    }

    if len(toLocate) != 0 {
        return 0, 0, errors.New("failed to locate all nodes")
    }

    return
}

func main() {
    t1 := template.New("v1")
    t1, err := t1.Parse(t1Text)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("failed to parse 1st template:", err)
    }

    t2 := template.New("v2")
    t2, err = t2.Parse(t2Text)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("failed to parse 2nd template:", err)
    }

    ctx := map[string]string{
        "IMAGE_PULL_SECRET": "whatever",
        "MYSQL_ADDRESS":     "orig_addr",
        "MYSQL_PORT":        "orig_port",
        "MYSQL_ADDRESS2":    "new_addr",
        "MYSQL_PORT2":       "new_port",
    }

    err = t1.Execute(os.Stdout, ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("failed to execute 1st template:", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(strings.Repeat("-", 80))

    err = merge(t1, t2)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("failed to merge:", err)
    }

    err = t1.Execute(os.Stdout, ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to execute modified template:", err)
    }
}
```

When run, this program produces:

```
instance_db_address: orig_addr
instance_db_port: orig_port
imagePullSecrets: whatever
resources:
  requests:
    memory: "1Gi"
    cpu: "512m"
  limits:
    memory: "1Gi"
    cpu: "1000m"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
instance_db_address: new_addr
instance_db_port: new_port
imagePullSecrets: whatever
resources:
  requests:
    memory: "1Gi"
    cpu: "512m"
  limits:
    memory: "1Gi"
    cpu: "1000m"
```

which means the actions of the two places of interest were actually changed in the original template.

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/r0txcr0W3GW).

To understand how the merging code works, start with the definition of [`template.Template`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template).

Comment: Thank you very much, but maybe you misunderstanded my question. I mean I want to merge the strings simply. When I merge, I don't know what the value would be rendered.

Comment: @clarenceLiu, I don't think I've misunderstood your question. You basically wanted to transform one template into another by changing two "actions" (as Go templates calls them–those `{{…}}` things) anchored at two specific places. Basically, leaving hackish solutions, like yours, aside, there's only a single way to do what you're after: properly parse both templates and then merge the "syntax trees" (AKA "parse trees"). Sure, if you only want to produce a _text_ of a merged template (say, to store it or transfer) my approach won't help as it supposes you want to execute the resulting template.

Comment: @clarenceLiu, that is not to somehow bash your solution–while definitely hackish, it's smart ;-) Anyway, I'd also pay attention to the Dave's comment: what you're doing smells like a solution to a non-problem.

Answer (score 0):

Haha, I have solved the problem for one day. I have come up with a good solution for the problem. The most difficult point is there are some special characters in the text, so I can't merge them use yaml package. Use code below can format the strings to simple yaml so that we can use Map to merge.

```
func FormatAppValueYaml(s string) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    var builder bytes.Buffer
    for _, v := range s {
        if SpecialChar(v) {
            builder.WriteRune('\\')
        }
        builder.WriteRune(v)
    }
    mp := make(map[string]interface{})
    err := yaml.Unmarshal(builder.Bytes(), &mp)
    return mp, err
}

func ResetAppValuesYaml(s string) string {
    var builder strings.Builder
    l := len(s)
    for i := 0; i < l; i++ {
        if i+1 < l && s[i] == '\\' && SpecialChar(rune(s[i+1])) {
            continue
        }
        builder.WriteRune(rune(s[i]))
    }
    return builder.String()
}

func SpecialChar(c rune) bool {
    return c == '\'' || c == '"' || c == '{' || c == '}' || c == '[' || c == ']'
}
```